# Sequence processing texts - why is padding 'pre' the default?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-processing

What's the intuition behind adding padding at the start of the text strings in preprocessors such as `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` ?

Would I be correct to assume that it is related to the fact that default truncation removes the start of strings? On that point, I guess I also don't understand why we think that ends of text strings would be more meaningful than the start.

Comment: You can use this to make all sentences of same length.

Comment: Yup I get what it does. I'm asking why it is that the the default option is to pad the *start* of the string rather than the end.